# Magento2: How to remove ‘Add New’ button from Admin Grid?

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

How can i remove add new button from my custom module?
I follow below link but the button did not remove
-> http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-how-to-remove-or-rename-add-new-button-from-admin-grid/

Comment: From which grid? the page you linked is for magento1 code.

Answer (score 3):

```
protected function _construct()
{
    $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Custom Name'); // to change the add new button value 
    parent::_construct();
    $this->buttonList->remove('add'); //to remove add button
    $this->buttonList->remove('save'); //to remove save button
    $this->buttonList->remove('reset'); //to remove reset button
    $this->buttonList->remove('delete'); // to remove delete button
}
```